# WORDPRESS - Visual Composer erasing data when press edit button

Tags: wordpress

I'm using visual composer that is a wonderfull add-on. The problem is that when I click the edit button of an element, the previous content is deleted ! Each time, I have to write again the content..

Do you know an issue ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have other plugins installed? Could any of them be interfering? Also, you may want to try get support from the developer.

Comment: No conflict with other possible :(